# reduce/filter array of objects by object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, object, ecmascript-6

Consider the following array of objects

```
const data = [{
    name: 'James',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Janet',
    sex: 'female',
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'female',
}];
```

I'd like to return the following:

```
{
  males: [{
    name: 'James',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    sex: 'male',
  }]
  females: [{
    name: 'Janet',
    sex: 'female',
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'female',
}]
}
```

I've tried mapping over the array, selecting objects by key then adding them to a new array, the result being two arrays.  From there, I don't know how to go about returning them in a new object in a succinct way.

I'm not too familiar with the array filter/reduce methods in ES6, would they be useful here?  Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce`

```js
const data = [{
  name: 'James',
  sex: 'male',
}, {
  name: 'Mike',
  sex: 'male',
}, {
  name: 'Janet',
  sex: 'female',
}, {
  name: 'Mary',
  sex: 'female',
}];

const result = data.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.sex] = c[v.sex] || [];       //Initiate if key does not exist
  c[v.sex].push(v);                //Push the value
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

If you want the keys to be plural, you can just append 's'

```
const result = data.reduce((c, v) => {
  let k = v.sex + 's';
  c[k] = c[k] || [];           //Initiate if key does not exist
  c[k].push(v);                //Push the value
  return c;
}, {});
```

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Something simple with plain old js -

```
const data = [{
    name: 'James',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Janet',
    sex: 'female',
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'female',
}];

var result = { males: [], females: []};
data.forEach(function(person){
  person.sex === 'male' ? result.males.push(person) : result.females.push(person);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank you, love the simplicity

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```js
const data = [{name:'James',sex:'male',},{name:'Mike',sex:'male',},{name:'Janet',sex:'female',},{name:'Mary',sex:'female',}];

var result = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  acc[obj.sex + "s"] = acc[obj.sex + "s"] || []; 
  acc[obj.sex + "s"].push(obj);
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const data = [{name: 'James',sex: 'male'}, {name: 'Mike',sex: 'male'}, {name: 'Janet',sex: 'female'}, {name: 'Mary',sex: 'female'}];
const result = data.reduce((a, c) => (a[c.sex + 's'].push(c), a), {males: [], females: []});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you answer your question?

```
const data = [{
    name: 'James',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Mike',
    sex: 'male',
  }, {
    name: 'Janet',
    sex: 'female',
  }, {
    name: 'Mary',
    sex: 'female',
}];
const sex = {};
data.forEach(item => {
    if (!sex[item.sex]) sex[item.sex] = [];
    sex[item.sex].push(item);
})
console.log(sex);
```

Comment: Yes, thank you - great solution, though I've picked the one using reduce above :)